# Imprimir sin vista previa en C#, ReportViewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer, impresión

os explico lo que necesito.

Tengo esta vista creada en c#, para una aplicacion de escritorio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como verán tengo otras 3 mas, las cuales las cargo en un **reportViewer**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces el proceso para imprimir es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces **-> presiono el botón pedido -> sale alerta de confirmación -> abre un nuevo `form` que contiene el reportViewer -> presiono icono de impresión -> sale la ventanita de impresión -> presiono imprimir -> imprime**.

> Vale Decir que el proceso de impresión es larga y molesta(eso creo), lo que deseo es que esto cambie a: **presiono el botón pedido -> sale alerta de confirmación ->imprime.**

Vale, os dejo el evento del botón:

```
    private void btn_cobrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (lista.Rows.Count == 0) {
            ToastNotification.Show(this, "Añade un producto antes de cobrar.", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
            return;
        }
  // mensaje de confirmacion
        if(MessageBox.Show("Esta Apunto de Cobrar el monto de " + lb_total_importe.Text + ".", "COBRAR PEDIDO", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)==DialogResult.Yes){
                aux = CCliente.Buscar("ci",cb_ci_nit.Text.ToString());
                if (aux.Rows.Count == 1 && lista.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataRow row_cliente = aux.Rows[0];
                    Numeracion num = new Numeracion();
                    MVentas venta = new MVentas(0, int.Parse(row_cliente["id"].ToString()),int.Parse(Datos.Rows[0]["id"].ToString()), DateTime.Now, Double.Parse(lb_total_importe.Text), num.Convertir(lb_total_importe.Text, true), "pedido", "cancelado");
                    long id_now = CVenta.Insertar(venta, this);
                    if (id_now != (-1))
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in lista.Rows)
                        {
                            string precio_total = r.Cells["total"].Value.ToString();
                            string cantidad = r.Cells["cantidad"].Value.ToString();
                            string unitario = r.Cells["precio"].Value.ToString();
                            string descripcion = r.Cells["descripcion"].Value.ToString();
                            int id = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["id"].Value);
                            MDetalleVenta det = new MDetalleVenta(0, id, double.Parse(cantidad), (int)id_now, Double.Parse(precio_total), descripcion, Double.Parse(unitario));
                            if (CDetalleVenta.Insertar(det, this))
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
 //aqui llamo al form de impresion
                    form_imprimir ff = new form_imprimir(id_now, "pedido");
                    ff.Visible = true;
                    limpiar();
                }
                else {
                    MessageBox.Show("El CI/Nit no esta registrado.\n Registre el Nombre y guardelo.");
                    btn_guardar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                    btn_guardar.Enabled = true;
                    tb_nombreAp.Text = "";
                    tb_nombreAp.Enabled = true;
                    tb_nombreAp.Focus();
                }
        }
    }
```

Y el `Load` de mi form de impresion:

```
    private void FormFactura_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tipo.CompareTo("factura") == 0)
        {
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "facturacion.Vistas.Report3.rdlc";
            DataTable factura = CFactura.MostrarID(id_venta);
            DataTable venta = CVenta.MostrarID(id_venta);
            DataTable infomacion = CEmpresa.Mostrar();
            DataTable codigo = CCodigo.ultimoID(int.Parse(factura.Rows[0]["idCodigo"].ToString()));
            DataTable cliente = CCliente.MostrarID(venta.Rows[0]["idCliente"].ToString());
            DataTable customer = CDetalleVenta.Mostrar((int)id_venta);
            this.MDetalleVentaBindingSource.DataSource = customer;
            ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[16];
            string path = "file:\\" + Application.StartupPath + infomacion.Rows[0]["logo"];
            string pathqr = "file:\\" + Application.StartupPath + factura.Rows[0]["QR"].ToString();
            parameters[15] = new ReportParameter("Path", @path, true);
            parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("PathQr", @pathqr, true);
            parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("empresa", infomacion.Rows[0]["nombre"].ToString());
            parameters[2] = new ReportParameter("propietario", infomacion.Rows[0]["nomPropietario"].ToString());
            parameters[3] = new ReportParameter("direccion", infomacion.Rows[0]["direccion"].ToString());
            parameters[4] = new ReportParameter("nit", infomacion.Rows[0]["nit"].ToString());
            parameters[5] = new ReportParameter("nro", factura.Rows[0]["numFactura"].ToString());
            parameters[6] = new ReportParameter("autorizacion", codigo.Rows[0]["autorizacion"].ToString());
            parameters[7] = new ReportParameter("telefono", infomacion.Rows[0]["telefono"].ToString());
            parameters[8] = new ReportParameter("literal","Son: "+ venta.Rows[0]["montoLiteral"].ToString());
            parameters[9] = new ReportParameter("nombre_cliente", cliente.Rows[0]["nombre"].ToString());
            parameters[10] = new ReportParameter("ci", cliente.Rows[0]["ci"].ToString());
            parameters[11] = new ReportParameter("fecha", venta.Rows[0]["fecVenta"].ToString());
            parameters[12] = new ReportParameter("total", venta.Rows[0]["montoTotal"].ToString());
            parameters[13] = new ReportParameter("codigo_control", factura.Rows[0]["codControl"].ToString());
            parameters[14] = new ReportParameter("fecha_limite", codigo.Rows[0]["fecFinal"].ToString());
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
            this.reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
        else {
            if (tipo.CompareTo("pedido") == 0)
            {
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "facturacion.Vistas.Report1.rdlc";
                DataTable venta = CVenta.MostrarID(id_venta);
                DataTable infomacion = CEmpresa.Mostrar();
                DataTable cliente = CCliente.MostrarID(venta.Rows[0]["idCliente"].ToString());
                DataTable customer = CDetalleVenta.Mostrar((int)id_venta);
                this.MDetalleVentaBindingSource.DataSource = customer;
                ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[2];
                string path = "file:\\" + Application.StartupPath + infomacion.Rows[0]["logo"];
                parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("nombre_cliente", cliente.Rows[0]["nombre"].ToString());
                parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("fecha", venta.Rows[0]["fecVenta"].ToString());
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
                this.reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
            else {
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "facturacion.Vistas.Report2.rdlc";
                DataTable venta = CVenta.MostrarID(id_venta);
                DataTable infomacion = CEmpresa.Mostrar();
                DataTable cliente = CCliente.MostrarID(venta.Rows[0]["idCliente"].ToString());
                DataTable customer = CDetalleVenta.Mostrar((int)id_venta);
                this.MDetalleVentaBindingSource.DataSource = customer;
                ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[10];
                string path = "file:\\" + Application.StartupPath + infomacion.Rows[0]["logo"];
                parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("Path", @path, true);
                parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("empresa", infomacion.Rows[0]["nombre"].ToString());
                parameters[2] = new ReportParameter("propietario", infomacion.Rows[0]["nomPropietario"].ToString());
                parameters[3] = new ReportParameter("direccion", infomacion.Rows[0]["direccion"].ToString());
                parameters[4] = new ReportParameter("telefono", infomacion.Rows[0]["telefono"].ToString());
                parameters[5] = new ReportParameter("nombre_cliente", cliente.Rows[0]["nombre"].ToString());
                parameters[6] = new ReportParameter("ci", cliente.Rows[0]["ci"].ToString());
                parameters[7] = new ReportParameter("fecha", venta.Rows[0]["fecVenta"].ToString());
                parameters[8] = new ReportParameter("total", venta.Rows[0]["montoTotal"].ToString());
                parameters[9] = new ReportParameter("literal", "Son: " + venta.Rows[0]["montoLiteral"].ToString());
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
                this.reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yo personalmente he utilizado el control "PrintDocument" para imprimir directamente sin intervencion del usuario y el control "PrintPreviewDocument" para previsualizar e imprimir con los mismos pasos que comentas. Saludos,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De tanto buscar y buscar y buscar...

Encontré una forma de hacerlo, que es implementando una clase de impresión, os explico los detalles en el código:

Lo primero que tenéis que hacer es crear una clase impresión:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
// el namespace depende de tu proyecto
namespace facturacion.Vistas
{
    public class Impresor : IDisposable
    {
        private int m_currentPageIndex;
        private IList<Stream> m_streams;

        // Stream que nos ayudara a contener el Report.rdlc 
        private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            m_streams.Add(stream);
            return stream;
        }

        // exportacion del archivo-reporte en formato EMF (Enhanced Metafile).
        private void Export(LocalReport report)
        {
           //las siguientes lineas definen el tamaño de la hoja, en mi caso es de tamaño ticket
            //los tamaños pueden ser en pulgadas(in) o en centimetros(cm), quiza aceptan mas formatos pero no los probé.
            string deviceInfo =
              @"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>7,7cm</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>35,5cm</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>0cm</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>0,2cm</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>0cm</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>0cm</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>";
            Warning[] warnings;
            m_streams = new List<Stream>();
            //renderizamos el reporte
            report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
            { stream.Position = 0; }
        }

        // Handler para los eventos PrintPageEvents
        private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
            Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

            // ajusta el area rectangular con margenes.
            Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                ev.PageBounds.Width,
                ev.PageBounds.Height);

            // Dibuja un fondo blanco para el reporte
            ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

            // Dibuja el contenido del reporte
            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

            // pasa a la siguiente pagina y comprueba que no se haya terminado el contenido
            m_currentPageIndex++;
            ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
        }

        private void Print()
        {
            PrintDocument printDoc;
            //busca el nombre de la impresora predeterminada
            String printerName = ImpresoraPredeterminada();

            if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("Error: No hay datos que imprimir.");

            printDoc = new PrintDocument();
            printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
            if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("No puedo encontrar la impresora \"{0}\".", printerName));
            }
            else
            {
                printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
                m_currentPageIndex = 0;
                printDoc.Print();
            }
        }

        private string ImpresoraPredeterminada()
        {
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
            {
                PrinterSettings a = new PrinterSettings();
                a.PrinterName = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i].ToString();
                if (a.IsDefaultPrinter)
                { return PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i].ToString(); }
            }
            return "";
        }

        // Exporta el reporte a un archivo .emf y lo imprime
        public void Imprime(LocalReport rdlc)
        {
            Export(rdlc);
            Print();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (m_streams != null)
            {
                foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                    stream.Close();
                m_streams = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bueno si no les gusta leer, lo pueden copiar y pegar, luego hacer unos pequeños cambios de hoja y namespace y estara listo.

Ahora paso al evento de mi boton y editare la parte donde llamaba al `form_impresion` es decir esta parte:

```
//aqui llamo al form de impresion
form_imprimir ff = new form_imprimir(id_now, "pedido");
ff.Visible = true;
```

Esa Parte se reemplazara con lo siguiente:

```
LocalReport rdlc = new LocalReport();//importante
rdlc.ReportPath = @"..\..\Vistas\Report1.rdlc";//direccion absoluta del reporte, es muy importante a la hora de ponerlo en funcionamiento.
// si os da algun error puede ser por no encontrar la direccion exacta del reporte, creedme ya lo pase.
rdlc.ReportEmbeddedResource = "facturacion.Vistas.Report1.rdlc";
// las siguientes lineas son los datos que nesecito para mi reporte.
DataTable customer = CDetalleVenta.Mostrar((int)id_now);
rdlc.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", customer));
DataTable venta2 = CVenta.MostrarID(id_now);
DataTable infomacion = CEmpresa.Mostrar();
DataTable cliente = CCliente.MostrarID(venta2.Rows[0]["idCliente"].ToString());
//los parametros dento de mi report.rdlc
ReportParameter nombre = new ReportParameter("nombre_cliente", cliente.Rows[0]["nombre"].ToString());
ReportParameter fecha = new ReportParameter("fecha", venta2.Rows[0]["fecVenta"].ToString());
rdlc.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[]{nombre,fecha});
// instancio un objeto dentro de la clase Impresor
Impresor imp = new Impresor();
imp.Imprime(rdlc);//llamo a la función e creedme imprime de fabula.
```

Espero que os ayude a unos cuantos con el mismo problema, ya que lo busque y leí bastante para poder hacerlo y entenderlo.

Con todo esto se soluciono y ahora el proceso es: **`presiono el botón pedido -> sale alerta de confirmación ->imprime.`**

Comment: Utilice ese código para mi proyecto y funciona bien pero cuando instalo en otra maquina me manda un error y los otros informes que los hago normal si me los muestra, que hago?

Comment: Depende del error que tengas, podrias [formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) mostrando el codigo que llevas y quiza diciendo que copiaste la resuesta que encontraste aqui.