# Como puedo imprimir mi factura completa en c#?

Tags: c#, print

Tengo un software  hecho en c#, para las impresiones pero cuando imprimo me imprime un pedazo de la factura, Factura debe ser las impresas de puntos ventas como la impresora Star SP500. Este es el código que utilizo para impresión.

```
private void DocumentoFactura_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int y = 0;
            //Titulo
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Sistema Xenesis", new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 300, 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(empresa.Nombre, new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 300, 20);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(empresa.Direccion, new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 300, 35);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Tel: " + empresa.Telefono1 + "/ " + empresa.Telefono2, new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 300, 35);
            //Datos
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Cliente: "+ Actualcliente.PrimerNombre, new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 50);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Codigo Cliente: " + Actualcliente.Codigo, new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 70);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Codigo De Compra: " + CodigoCompra, new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 90);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Fecha: " + Fecha, new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 110);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Sucursal: "+empresa.Sucursal , new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 130);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("RNC: " + empresa.RNC, new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 150);


            //Rayas
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2), new Point(90, 145), new Point(755, 145));
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2), new Point(90, 175), new Point(755, 175));
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2), new Point(90, 1110), new Point(755, 1110));
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2), new Point(90, 1140), new Point(755, 1140));
            //Compras
            e.Graphics.DrawString("CANT.", new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 100, 150);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("DESCRIPCION", new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 180, 150);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("DESCUENTO", new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 380, 150);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("PRECIO UNIT.", new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 580, 150);

            for (int i = 0; i < dgbProductos.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                y = 178 + (20 * i + 1);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dgbProductos.Rows[i].Cells["Cantidad"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 110, y);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dgbProductos.Rows[i].Cells["Producto"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 180, y);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dgbProductos.Rows[i].Cells["cDescuento"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 380, y); 
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dgbProductos.Rows[i].Cells["Precio"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 580, y);

            }

            e.Graphics.DrawString("Total: "+Dinero, new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 535, y + 20);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Dinero: " + txtdinero.Text.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 523, y + 35);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Devuelta: " + string.Format("{0}", int.Parse(txtdinero.Text.ToString()) - Dinero), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 507, y + 50);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("GRACIAS POR SU COMPRA", new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 300, 1115);
```

Comment: pues independientemente de la impresora, seria bueno que tomes el tamaño de la hoja como algo muy importante. yo lo consegui de otra forma lo puedes ver [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176992/imprimir-sin-vista-previa-en-c-reportviewer/177313), cualquier consulta estare atento

Comment: Como le ponente loc componentes a reporte?

Comment: utilice el reportViewer de C#, el codigo que tienes en esta pregunta la verdad no la conosco como repote, solo parece estar dibujando una imagen...

Comment: si porque lo dibuje.

Comment: Pues no parace ser la mejor opcion para sacar reportes..., deberias de estudiar un poco de reportViewer, veras que no es dificil