# Imprimir sin vista previa en C#, ReportViewer, Intentando correr un codigo encontrado, liado

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer, imprimir, rdlc

Buen Dia, e intentado realizar una impresion directa del reporte rdlc sin ver  el ReportViewer, e seguido la respuesta del Usuario @Shassain

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/177313/255669

,canbie nameSpace por el de mi proyecto. Ahora en el evento del Boton Imprimir de mi formulario ventas: implemento el  codigo mostrado para el evento del boton: mi Pregunta es la siguiente para esta parte del codigo:

```
DataTable customer = CDetalleVenta.Mostrar((int)id_now);
```

rdlc.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", customer));

COmo puedo remplazar estos datos por los mios, los datos que recibo de mi DataSet1, vienen de un procedimiento alamcenado en MariaDB, en mi DataSet1 "DS_Reportes", donde tengo mis DataTable "ImprimirVenta" de donde saco los datos que necesito para mi reporte.cabe resaltar que logro imrimir el Reporte.rdlc visualizandolo en el reportViewer sin ningun problema. Entonces que datos de mi "DataSet1"; Necesito poner en esta Linea ?:

De acuerdo a la informacion que yo manejo.

Gracias de antemano

lo siguiente es lo que tengo que canbiar de acuerdo a mis datos y solamente logre avanzar hazta la primera parte :

```
LocalReport rdlc = new LocalReport();
                rdlc.ReportPath = @"..\..\Reportes\Rpt_Imprimirventa.rdlc";
                rdlc.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Presentacion.Reportes.Rpt_Imprimirventa.rdlc";
                
                DataTable customer = CDetalleVenta.Mostrar((int)id_now);
                rdlc.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", customer));
                DataTable venta2 = CVenta.MostrarID(id_now);
                DataTable infomacion = CEmpresa.Mostrar();
                DataTable cliente = CCliente.MostrarID(venta2.Rows[0]["idCliente"].ToString());
               
                ReportParameter nombre = new ReportParameter("nombre_cliente", cliente.Rows[0]["nombre"].ToString());
                ReportParameter fecha = new ReportParameter("fecha", venta2.Rows[0]["fecVenta"].ToString());
                rdlc.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { nombre, fecha });
                
                Impresor imp = new Impresor();
                imp.Imprime(rdlc);
```

El DataTable "ImprimirVenta" es el que alimenta a mi reporte Rdlc que se llama Rpt_Imprimirventa.rdlc,

cuando visualizo el reporte en el reportviewer visor obtengo el "codigo_ve" codigo de venta, atravez del campo de texto que tengo en el formulario donde esta el reportviewer.

Adjunto algunas imagenes y gracias por la intervencion @Yussef, pido disculpas por la falta de informacion.
..!Estoy aprendiendo a andar por estos caminos!

[image: DataTable Imprimir Venta]

[image: DataSet1]

[image: Rpt_ImprimirVenta.rdlc]

De Esta forma Guardo los datos de mi formulario y optengo el codigo de venta "codigo_ve" para poer identificar la venta a imprimir

```
else //Procedemos al guardados de los datos
        {
            string Rpta = "";
            //oVe.Codigo_ve;               
            oVe.Codigo_tipdoc2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmbTipodoc2.SelectedValue);
            oVe.Nrodocumento_ve = "0";
            oVe.Fechahora_ve = Dtp_fecha.Value;
            oVe.Subtotal_ve = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubtotal_ve.Text);
            oVe.Impuesto_ve = Convert.ToDecimal(txtImpuesto_ve.Text);
            oVe.Importetotal_ve = Convert.ToDecimal(txtImportetotal_ve.Text);
            //oVe.codigo_cl
            //oVe.Codigo_dmp
            oVe.Dineroentrega_cliente = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDineroentrega_cliente.Text);
            oVe.Vueltoal_cliente = Convert.ToDecimal(txtVueltoal_cliente.Text);
            oVe.Codigo_us = nCodigo_us;

            Datos.D_Ventas Datos = new Datos.D_Ventas();
            Rpta = Datos.Guardar_ve(nEstadoguarda, oVe);

            bool esNumero = int.TryParse(Rpta, out int xCodigo);
            if (esNumero == true)
            {
                string Rpta2 = "";
                oVe.Codigo_ve = Convert.ToInt32(Rpta); //Código de venta generado

                String Codigo_ve = oVe.Codigo_ve.ToString();
```

Comment: Pero como voy a saber yo que datos tienes tu, si no has mostrado nada de ello?  Tienes que ir viendo que nombre le pusiste a los parámetros y datasets del reporte y agregarlos a mano, tal como hace el código de la otra pregunta

Comment: Gracias por responder, e agregado algunos datos mas, seria granadioso para mi si puede orientarme enseñandome a llegar a mi solucion.

Comment: Ahora va mejorando!! . Te aparece algún error ?? recuerda que la ruta en rdlc.ReportPath debe ser correcta

Comment: Otra duda que me queda, es si sabes llenar un Datatable con los datos de tu base de datos, mismos datos que van en el reporte

Comment: bueno e logrado imprimir el reporte con los datos de mi base de  datos logro impriir el ticket, Pero con el visualizador. aun no logro correr ya que en la parate del codigo  que muestro  a continuacion  figuran datos que no son mios como "CDetalleventa","CVenta","CEmpresa", etc. Esos no son mis datos de el DataTable IprimirVenta.

Comment: la informacion que necesito esta en el DataTable "ImprimirVenta" que mostre en laimagen:  muestro parate del codigo que necesito canbiar de acuerdo ami informacion

Comment: DataTable customer = CDetalleVenta.Mostrar((int)id_now);
                    rdlc.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", customer));
                    DataTable venta2 = CVenta.MostrarID(id_now);
                    DataTable infomacion = CEmpresa.Mostrar();
                    DataTable cliente = CCliente.MostrarID(venta2.Rows[0]["idCliente"].ToString());